# Using Persist from Zustand for state management in localStorage

Tags: reactjs, zustand

Is it possible to only persist certain states from the Zustand store and not all?

For instance I have the following:

```
import {create} from "zustand"

export const useAuthStore = create((set, get) => ({
user: null,
isError: false,
isLoading: false,
message; "",
register: async() => {
  //some function
},
getUser: async() => {
  set({ isLoading: true });
try{
  const resp = await fetch(API_URL + "/getuser", {
      method: "GET",
      credentials: "include",
  });

  const userData = await resp.json();
  if (resp.ok) {
                set({ isLoading: false, isSuccess: true, isLoggedIn: true, user: 
   {...userData} });
  };
} catch(error) {
console.log(error);
}
}
//Some other functions below
}))
```

In this case, what I would like to store in localStorage is the **user** from my getUser function so I can access the first name (to display it in the nav bar) when refreshing the website.

Is it possible to use persist middleware to accomplish this (as shown here https://blog.openreplay.com/zustand-state-management-for-react/) or rather I need to directly use the localStorage parameter as shown in this blog: https://medium.com/@1992season/manage-states-using-zustand-and-localstorage-7d66ff12cad6 ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, it is possible** to persist only certain states from the Zustand store. Zustand provides a **[partialize](https://docs.pmnd.rs/zustand/integrations/persisting-store-data#partialize)** option that allows you to pick some of the state’s fields to be stored in the storage.

Here are two examples:

**1. Omitting multiple fields:**

```js
export const useBoundStore = create(
      persist(
        (set, get) => ({
          foo: 0,
          bar: 1,
        }),
        {
          partialize: (state) =>
            Object.fromEntries(
              Object.entries(state).filter(([key]) => !['foo'].includes(key))
            ),
        }
      )
    );
```

In this example, the foo field will not be persisted.

**2. Allowing only specific fields:**

```js
export const useBoundStore = create(
  persist(
    (set, get) => ({
      foo: 0,
      bar: 1,
    }), {
      partialize: (state) => ({
        foo: state.foo,
      }),
    }
  )
);
```

In this example, only the foo field will be persisted.